What is a man, and why?
What exactly is a man? Is an eunuch a man? Is it a feeling? If you could surgically implant a womb and induce pregnancy, would that also be a man? Can someone who has developed mammary tissue be called a man? Do the bones, genes etc. also play a role? Or is it a mix of all of this?
This question is for writing purposes as I wish to write a story exploring the extremes of gender roles.

I think this question's closing is unjustified. The topic is controversial but the question is undoubtedly about philosophy.

@edelex is the question about philosophy, or is it just semantics?  Your own description makes it sound like this question actually belongs on English Language and Usage Stackexchange: "A man is what we point to when we label something with the word 'man', and while different people point to different things when calling them 'men'..."

I think the poster's intent is philosophical - they are showing how gender has qualities of the sorties paradox and want help exploring the "conventional" boundaries.

@Obarou, that said: for fiction writing purposes, I feel like the answer is that you should pose interesting questions and not try to resolve them neatly into one little bundle.

Philosophy is not about word usage.

@David Gudeman With all due respect, I wasn't asking about the word 'man', but the quality of being man

@Obarou, "the quality of being man" has no more inherent meaning than "man" does.

The recent polemic about olympic boxer Imane Khelif has proven this is a difficult question, as even proponents of gender normativity had to admit someone can have a full set of female reproductive organs, be born and raised and behave as a woman all their life and still, according to them, not be a woman...

The focus on "man" rather than on the set of (almost) all nouns — which are almost all fuzzy — the question seems especially arbitrary to me.

All categories of physical objects are fuzzy around the edges, and zooming in on those fuzzy edges is not philosophy. The question of whether a eunuch a man is of no more interest philosophically than the question of whether a hotdog is a sandwich or the question of whether an SUV is a car.
Whether an individual is male or human is a matter for biology. Whether an individual is an adult is generally a matter of law or custom, although there is also a biological meaning of "adult" (sexual maturity) which one might use instead.
None of this is philosophy.

And the fuzziness is not limited to physical objects, but the meaning of almost every noun (as well as other parts of speech).  I believe that an awareness of this fuzziness is very important in philosophy.

There is no full, coherent definition of a man that encompasses all things we would consider men and excludes all things we would consider non-men, as with most objects. This also applies to humans, cameras, chairs, etcetera.
Ultimately, it's a mix. A man is what we point to when we label something with the word 'man', and while different people point to different things when calling them men, it's basically always a mixture of:

What they see in terms of physical attributes. (Not necessarily the attributes themselves, that is only in certain contexts. Consider how someone may wear certain clothes to hide their breasts, or makeup to hide certain traditionally 'gendered' facial features or accentuate others).
Expression (what clothes they wear, what their demeanor is like, etcetera).
Feeling (particularly when you are calling yourself a man, but you also may see someone else as a man if they have told you, or you suspect, that they 'feel like a man', or that they may realise in the future that they feel like a man).

We can see this partially with the fact that even ardent conservatives who say that biological sex is exclusively what determines someone's gender will categorise someone based on their gender expression and physical attributes gained through gender affirming care, even when this contradicts their 'adult human female' definition, which itself isn't complete due to ambiguities between the sexes (see Ben Shapiro accidentally calling a trans woman a woman). It also probably happens on the other side, where somebody who thinks self-identification is the ultimate factor will categorise someone's gender based on their expression and physical characteristics, even when this contradicts their self-identification. People can try to maintain using their own definitions, but ultimately we can't control that a man is something we call a 'man', and given any definition attempting to be complete, there will be always be a counterexample or a situation in which someone who adheres to it theoretically won't in practice.

For what it is worth, the Jewish Orthodox position on this matter, as I understand it, is that human beings are either male or female, but sometimes we simply cannot know the sex of a person. Just thought I would mention that for balance :)

@TomW  Not that I'm a fan of them, but the Heritage Foundation made a very similar point around the argument about "edge cases" in gender classification: they argue that any gender undecidability is an epistemological issue, not an ontological issue. You don't invent a third gender because we have a hard time knowing someone's binary gender.

@Annika - thanks, a great point :) Blessings (if you accept them ;) )

@Annika "I have decided a priori that there are only two categories and I am just gonna ignore the actual cases that don't fit with my preconceptions" is the very definition of an ideological position and, TBH, not very sane.

@armand -- again, not a fan of heritage, but they do give some rational basis for this (very much along the lines of Kathleen Stock's thinking -- and she's no philosophical slouch).

Annika: "You don't invent a third gender because we have a hard time knowing someone's binary gender."
Maybe not, but depending on how hard knowing someone's gender is, this may lead us to question whether the traditional 2-gender classification is serving us well.

@DanielAsimov I find it interesting that I simply post a link saying the same thing as Tom W and have stated several times I’m not defending it so I’m not sure why you are directing comments at me. Read the article and write the author to share your thoughts.

I am responding to your comment above, which I partially quoted. It looked to me as if what I quoted was what you believe. If that is wrong, I apologize. But it sure looked that way.

I am also curious why you would post a statement (in a comment) that you don't believe.

@DanielAsimov because it was germane to the post and Tom Ws comment.

Great. I hope that, next time, it is clearer to me that you are posting someone else's opinion and not your own.

The word "man" is just one of many examples of nouns that have "fuzzy edges" — i.e., that cannot be exactly defined without some arbitrary choices.
It's like trying to define exactly where the surface of a cloud is in the sky.
In fact, this fuzziness applies to almost all nouns, to some degree or other.
The only nouns exempt from fuzziness seem to be mathematical definitions.
And possibly elementary particles. But then, they have their fuzziness, don't they.

I wouldn't say there is one definition or framing, that we can arrive at what it 'ultimately' means.
Wittgenstein would point to the different contexts, the different language games, that use the terms. So mostly we have behavioural expectations and facilities assigned by sex and we can use man and woman to indicate them. Language is use.
There have always been people born with intersex characteristics, related to chromosome or developmental anomolies, and there things get more complicated. In this biological context a eunach definitely would be a man, even if 'cut' before puberty like the castrato singers in Italy. Interestingly the human Y chromosome is dissappearing, will dissappear completely, and wasn't how our ancient ancestors determined biological sex: Extinction of chromosomes due to specialization is a universal occurrence (paper in Nature).
The Olympic Committee have taken a particular stance, that everyone should be able to compete either as male, or female. Because male hormones count as performance enhancers, this has led to a regime based on hormone levels over the most recent two years. But some things like higher bone density in those born male, don't change. The issues around Imane Khelif (born with a male chromosome but developed as female) and rightwing anger about her comoeting as a woman, while confidently asserting sex is defined by the genitals a person is born with, point to hypocrisy - implicitly many rightwing commentators are saying she isn't male or female, demanding some kind of additional category.
Gender is the social performance of sex, and there has always been an array of ways people behave, more or less strongly showing gender-specific behaviours. One theory goes that greater social pressures for gender-conformity arose with industrialisation, where limiting roles for women outside the home/homestead helped to provide working men as a commodity to the economy, who needed at least one full-time worker at home to support them. The Moral Foundations theory (Wikipedia link) of Haidt et al, suggests that feeling under threat leads to 'activation' of a greater pressures on social conformity like gender expression, and lower tolerance of ambiguity, and resistance to things seen as indicating social change. The converse is that when people feel secure and safe, they tend to have greater tolerance of ambiguity, which in general supports creativity and social change.
There is an important positive role for gender expression, in terms of meeting a partner. If you want to have children, you will be looking for cues to indicate whether that is possible. It's interesting to me that having blue hair can be a non-explicit way for a woman to suggest they are seeking a woman partner. See Gendered associations of pink and blue. But then also bright coloured hair being picked up by the meme world as indicators of gender non-conformity. Many new fashions started as ways for gay men to indicate their sexuality and preferences. And most of the rest of gendered fashion has a role in sexual signalling, for instance emphasising cues indicating fertility, arousal, or likelihood of healthy births. But, gender assymetry, like different body sizes, in general in the fossil record, correlates with extinction risk: New driver of extinction: Adaptations for sexual selection.
'Man' can be used hyperbolically, in reference to an ideal, like 'real man' or manliness. In such informal discourse many behaviours are described as not 'manly', and this is a big part of the social policing of gender expressions. There was an interesting study in 2015: Insights into Sexism, Male Status and Performance Moderates Female-Directed Hostile and Amicable Behaviour (PLoS journal article). This seems to indicate that a major driver of sexist behaviour is feeling insecure in the social hierachy. There are differences in how manly and feminine are used, with the former generally being about capacities and capability not attractiveness, whereas in regards to women attractiveness is central even paramount, for those policing gender roles.
In the Ancient Greek and Roman world there was a big emphasis on masculinity as the power to penetrate and dominate, and male homosexuality was considered less problematic than in this Christian world, at least if they conformed to this social role. But effeminacy and being in a sexually recieving or submissive role, were seen as literally unmanly. A eunuch wouldn't a man, or not a 'complete' one in this context. The same pattern is found in Ancient China, where being a eunuch was required to enter the Forbidden City of the Chinese Court, with a functional impact that they couldn't overthrow the government to start their own dynasty or cuckold the emperor, but they were always in tension with Confucian officials over perceptions they didn't follow traditional virtues in various ways (see eg Eunuchs in China, on Wikipedia).
On lactation, see Strange but True: Males Can Lactate.
Womb transplants (first done succesfully in 2023) and the extension of synthetic organ techniques to wombs, could in future allow people born male to give birth. Synthetic wombs could remive the gendered role for pregnancy and birth completely in future.
